# How to avoid cyclical dependency injection in php?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I can have two classes that are on the same level, for example in a service or domain layer. For each of them to work, you may need to refer to the another class.

For example:

```
class User
{
    public function __construct(
        protected Phone $phone
    ) {
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone->number;
    }
}

class Phone 
{
    public function __construct(
        protected User $user
    ) {
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user->name;
    }
}
```

And here there is a cyclical dependency injection. What should I do?

Comment: Have a logical structure that is not circular…‽

Comment: Cyclic dependencies often happen when called become to big, and have too many responsibilities. In your case, `Phone` contains both the number and gets access to the user name, which might be more than needed. You might try to move the `getUser` behavior to a different class (e.g. `User`) or create a new class with that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](https://github.com/jamolkhon/Sharbat) git repository, this is the semi-implementation of java GUICE dependency injection framework that introduced fo dependency injections problem. also if you want to handling it by yourself, then based on [this](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) article you needs to a third class as bellow :

```
class C {
   C(){}
}

class A {
   final C c;
   A(C c){ this.c = c;}
}

class B {
   final A a;
   final C c;
   B(A a, C c){ this.a = a; this.c = c; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The link to the article made me think